# Re-run protractor timeout or failed tests

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I didn't find any reference for the possibility to re-run failed tests (using protractor).
Do you know how to do that?
It would be great because I have a lot of tests and I don't like to run again all the tests to verify whether the previously failed tests passes or not.

Do anyone have experience with it?
It would like this:

- run all tests
- collect failed tests and run those again (maybe I can set somehow the re-try limit like 2 or 3 times)
- show the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, currently it is not possible, but there is an open feature request:

- [Feature to execute failed tests only](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1190)

Answer (score 2):

As of sept 9th 2016, the only way that's available to rerun failed tests in your cucumber/protractor e2e tests is with NickTomlin's protractor-flake.

Protractor-flake is "***a wrapper for protractor to automatically re-run failed specs for a specific number of attempts"***, check out these two links for steps on how to implement it:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake
2. https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake/blob/master/docs/cucumber.md

Please pay attention to the Caveat section under that NPM link above:

***Caveats**

This has not yet been tested with Protractor + Mocha. It should function similarly. Please update with an issue or PR if this is not the case.

Tests will not re-run properly (all tests will run each time) if you use a custom reporter that does not log stacktraces for failed tests. For example, if you are using jasmine-spec-reporter with Jasmine 2.0, make sure to set displayStacktrace: 'specs' or displayStacktrace: 'all'.*

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber has own property to rerun failed tests, you just need to paste:

```js
cucumberOpts : {
        require : [
            '...'
        ],
        format : 'rerun:path/to/@rerun.txt'
    }
```

and then to run tests using this file.

Comment: how to 'run tests using this file' in a protractor-cucumber setup?