# How to run only failed tests in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

In my js file I have defined a bunch of test case, some of them sometimes fails and I would like to re-run just these failed. 
Anyone could advise some ready feature which I could use or some another solution? It's really inconvenient and time-consuming running everything once again. The below example may show you how my spec looks like.

```
describe('Test -> Users table with admin privileges', function () {
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var welcomePage = new WelcomePage();
var usersPage = new UsersPage();

beforeEach(function () {
    LogIn.asAdmin1();
    clickWithWait(welcomePage.usersButton);
    browser.wait(hasNonZeroCount(usersPage.allRows), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'users list did not appear');
});

afterEach(function () {
    welcomePage.logout();
});

it('verifies counter on active tab', function () {
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(usersPage.allRows.first()), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'firstRow was not visible ');
    usersPage.allRows.count().then(function (count) {
        expect(usersPage.activeTab.getText()).toContain('Active' + ' (' + count + ')');
    });
});

it('verifies counter on archived tab', function () {
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(usersPage.allRows.first()), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'firstRow was not visible ');
    // Initial condition for case of none archived user have to be added here (it will remove if statement).
    clickWithWait(usersPage.archivedTab);
    usersPage.allRows.count().then(function (count) {
        if (count > 0) {
            expect(usersPage.archivedTab.getText()).toContain('Archived' + ' (' + count + ')');
        } else {
            console.log("Test Ignored due to none records")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-run protractor timeout or failed tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725237/re-run-protractor-timeout-or-failed-tests)

Comment: This can help: [How to run a single specific test case when using protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24536865/498238).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A somewhat mature solution was proposed by NickTomlin with ***protractor-flake***

Protractor-flake is "***a wrapper for protractor to automatically re-run failed specs for a specific number of attempts***", check out these two links for steps on how to implement it:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake
2. https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake/blob/master/docs/cucumber.md

Please *pay attention to the Caveat section* under that NPM link above:

***Caveats**

This has not yet been tested with Protractor + Mocha. It should function similarly. Please update with an issue or PR if this is not the case.

Tests will not re-run properly (all tests will run each time) if you use a custom reporter that does not log stacktraces for failed tests. For example, if you are using jasmine-spec-reporter with Jasmine 2.0, make sure to set displayStacktrace: 'specs' or displayStacktrace: 'all'.*